# GET[] fails to work when one parameter is missing =value?

Tags: php, get

The end of my query string looks like:

```
tweetpushr.php?attachments&id=20&tweetbody=Wassup%20David.%20Love%20you%20like%20a%20brutha&catid=6&catid2=6&catid3=10&dtpub=0000-00-00%2000:00:00&dtpush=0000-00-00%2000:00:00&usrpush=&id=20&tweetbody=Just%20a%20little%20more%20CSS%20and%20some%20polish%20man.&catid=8&catid2=1&catid3=1&dtpub=0000-00-00%2000:00:00&dtpush=0000-00-00%2000:00:00&usrpush=
```

I am trying to use `$_GET['tweetbody']` to access it variable but it looks as if the attachments modifier does not have an `=` and is preventing me from getting the variable.

How do I get the value for tweetbody?

Comment: I accidentally edited out the full URL which is important -- I can't seem to revert either. Please re-add it. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: @pst I had it in my editor and have put it back...

Comment: Just curious: What happens when you `print_r( $_GET['tweetbody'] );`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason that the missing `=` from `attachments` would prevent you from getting at any of the rest of the variables. The `attachments` item will simply be populated with an empty string, and the rest of the variables will be parsed normally. Just try a script with `<?php var_dump($_GET); ?>` in it and pass the string above and you will see that all keys/values appear as you would expect them to.

However, the `tweetbody` key appears twice in the query string (as do most other keys) - is this the reason it doesn't have the value you expect it to?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending "tweetbody" twice... I think you should rewrite your querystring using [] after the variable names (so you can read them as an array), or better send it encoded as JSON or something like that.